# Adding fields to user's personal info in Django admin page

Tags: django, django-admin, user-profile

I just started a Django project (there are no apps in it). I activated the `admin` in settings file and can access the Django administration page. There is a column in Django page to add users; while adding users I get only three fields under personnal info, but I need to store some more information about users. I Googled around and found that I can use user profiles to accomplish this. I tried, but I am having problems.

My aim is to add three more fields to the user table:

1. role
2. contact number
3. other

I need details like: which function I need to write and where to do this.

I found [this](http://blog.bripkens.de/2011/04/adding-custom-profiles-to-the-django-user-model/), but I do not know where I need to write these steps. I would greatly appreciate a more clear explanation of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django User Profiles is what you need. The blog you linked to has clear steps on how to do it. You can check out the Django documentation. http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile also provides a good explanation.
Basically you need to create a new model with User as ForeignKey and define the model in the `settings.py` as `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "django_app.your_profile_modelname"`. Create the profile and save it just like any other model, and access it using `user.get_profile()`

Adding a couple of things in response to your questions below:
First, do not create apps as a directory. Use `startapp <appname> [destination]` as described here. That will create the app directory. 
Second, you have to add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the project's settings file, do a `syncdb`. Basically, follow the steps in [Django tutorial on writing your first app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). 
Third, `UserProfile` is a separate model. It is not an extension of `User`. It is associated with the `User` just because you added `User` as the `ForeignKey`. 
Fourth, to be able to see the user profile model in admin, you do exactly what you would [do to add any other model to admin page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/). Create a file names `admin.py` under your app with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.app.models import UserProfile
admin.site.register(UserProfile)
```

Comment: as described by you and turkeylinux site, i created one file named models.py under a directory named apps, then added AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'mysite.apps.UserProfile' here my site the project name, apps is a directory inside mysite dir, inside this app directory i had created the file models.py having following content

Comment: from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField("Website", blank=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

then uses command to sync db, after that again i checked in my admin page there were no extra fields available. still i am getting same three fields first name, last name and email. my aim is to add some more fields in db and populate using admin page.

Comment: What fields do you see in `UserProfile` model on admin page? You have added fields to `UserProfile`, not to `User`. Hence they will be visible under `UserProfile` model.

Answer (score 1):

There are three key concepts to understand:

1. There is no built in "profile" system in Django, beyond the limited `auth` app which is really geared just to user login. You are expected to roll your own.
2. There is nothing magical about a profile record in itslef, it is just like any other record that takes `User` as a foreign key (or, more properly, a [one-to-one field as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)). You create it by creating a custom django app (traditionally called `profiles`) and a model for that app (traditionally called `UserProfile`, since `Profile` is not allowed as a model name).
3. The only thing that sets `UserProfile` aparts as a model is that you specify it as the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` which means that it is accessible when called `.get_profile()` on a `User` record. That's it. If you set up the `UserProfile` like so:

   ```
   def UserProfile(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
       other fields
   ```

   then you can also access the profile as `user.profile` rather than `user.get_profile()` which some people prefer.

Again, nothing magical about the profile model -- it is just a model record like any other model record.

If you want to be able to edit additional fields within the user form that's more complicated; easiest way is probable unregister `User` and then register it again using your custom `ModelAdmin` and form class but judging by your question you're probably not at that level yet.